# Multiple plots, multiple characters and multiple point of views in a single novel

Tags: creative-writing, novel, perspective

I am wondering if this is at all possible. Usually, you have one plot and the plot is centered around one main character, but what if there are multiple main characters associated with a unique plot for each of them. Is this something that was done before? Usually, a story is told from one character's perspective, but I am wondering if it's possible to have several main characters, a unique plot for each of them and have the story told from their first person perspectives. If it can be done, then how do you tell your readers that whose character's first person perspective you're writing from since you switch all the time?

Comment: Game of Thrones demonstrates how to establish multiple POV, multiple threads and multiple story lines in a single novel.  Each novel in Songs of Fire & Ice also uses the same methd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to have several plots woven into one novel.  The thing is that it's more difficult than a single plot.

The most common is that one plot is clearly main and the others are subordinate, but it is possible to have one where it's impossible to pick out which one is the main.

The main issue is that you need something to make the novel cohere as a whole, and not just be a series of short stories that are, to add to the difficulty, chopped up and interspaced with each other.  They have to be confined in time and place and interact and react and otherwise form a whole.

L.M. Montgomery's *A Tangled Web* is such a tale.  In it, the matriarch Aunt Becky, having summoned a family meeting in which she announced various bequests, tells them that in a year, the person to inherit the most valuable heirloom will be announced at another such meeting.  This triggers a number of plots, sometimes angling for a chance to inherit, others merely triggered by the bequests or other events of the meeting.  It is tied off by the year limit.

Rick Cook's *Limbo System* also, revolving about an interstellar mission that accidentally makes first contact.  Various humans have various responses, the aliens interact with us, things happen that interrelated. It gets tied off in the end with the captain declaring a decision about a certain aspect of the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I have read novels with multiple plots, and also novels with multiple main characters and multiple POVs. I don't see a reason why a novel couldn't do both at the same time (but I can't recall an example).

One thing to look out for when you have multiple plots, is that they should integrate into a bigger narrative. Otherwise you are just interleaving unrelated stories, instead of writing one story with multiple (sub)plots.
Trudi Canavan's "Thief's Magic" severely suffers from this, in my opinion, because it reads like it alternates chapters between two barely related books (only one of which I enjoyed, unfortunately).

Switching viewpoints between characters is not a big problem. For example in Max Barry's "Providence" the chapters switch between viewpoints of the four main characters. Above each chapter title it states which character's POV it is in square brackets; e.g. [Anders].
In Audrey Niffenegger's "the Time Traveller's Wife" the character's POV is shown by preceding each section of text with the name, like "Clare: <text>". In addition it also adds dates above many sections, because it jumps through time as well as POV.

So yes, you can do both these things separately, and there is no reason why you couldn't do both at the same time.

Comment: Do you have an example excerpt of how to indicate a switch in view point?

Comment: @Sayaman In Jurassic Park, it is marked by a heading stating the character's name. I've done it previously by changing the font around for each character. There are a bunch of ways to do it.